# Sudden errors intersecting NDVI raster data with overlapping polygons in GME

Tags: raster, arcmap, ndvi, intersect, gme

I am experiencing errors with Geospatial Modeling Environment (GME) that suddenly developed after things were working perfectly.

**Description of software installed:** ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop and ArcGIS Service Pack: 0 (build 0); R version 3.3.2; Geospatial Modelling Environment (Version 0.7.4.0)

**What I'm trying to do**

- I am using the tool "isectpolyrst." My polygon file has 5718 rows
  with overlapping buffers. Buffer size is 90m around points. I am
  trying to extract Normalized Difference Vegetation Index raster data
  (NDVI; from MODIS) to each polygon. NDVI values range from -2000 to 9000
- I do not get an error message. However, the values of the raster I am trying to extract do not match the output. See below.
- The tool processes very, very quickly. The output value for each
  polygon is identical (mean = -1.797693e+308). These values are not
  correct (ie there is variation and the values do not match) The
  tricky part is the **tool worked properly until a few weeks ago**. I did
  not upgrade GIS, nor did I change the files at all.

**3. What I've tried to trouble shoot:**

- Double check projections are the same for polygon and raster data.
  Downloading NDVI files again. Perhaps they got corrupted?
- Scaling my data to 0-100 values (subtract by minimum value, divide by range, multiply by 100).
- Converting to different raster file type (TIFF, IMAGINE, GRID)
- Assigning attribute table to NDVI raster data (no luck)
- Try on different machines (all have Windows)
- Using the Zonal Stats as Table II in ArcMap. This is a finicky tool and I can never get it to work on >300 rows.

I AM STUMPED!!! Does anyone have any ideas on how to proceed? This is an issue I've heard from other folks, but no one found a work around in GME.

Comment: NDVI values should range from -1 to 1. You need to multiply MODIS NDVI raster ranged -2000 to 9000 by 0.0001 factor (see tab **Layers** in https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mod13q1). This could be a reason for the bad performance of "isectpolyrst" tool.

Comment: Just tried - still the same errors of -1.797693e+308 in each cell. My guess is that GME has an issue with the structure of the data, not the values themselves.